# Difference between justify-content vs align-items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a really hard time understanding what's the difference? From my research it seems like `justify-content` can do... `space-between` and `space-around`, while `align-items` can do... `stretch`, `baseline`, `initial` and `inherit`?

Also looks like both properties share, `flex-start`, `flex-end` and `center`.

Is there and dis/advantages to using one over the other or is it just preference? I feel like they are way to similar to just do the same thing anyone know the difference? thanks!!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: One works on the main axis, the other on the cross axis. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: Nope...justify-content deals with the elements on the main axis, align items the cross axis

Comment: Yeah..this should really be a dupe of that question.

Comment: @paulie_D not trying to ask dupe questions, but its the axis part that I was having a hard time understanding thank you for your help!!

Comment: This is certainly not a duplicate question. The answer works for both, but the question for each is different.

Answer (score 330):

Both set the alignment of the content.

## 1. `justify-content:` along *primary* axis

(set horizontal alignment/spacing if flex-direction is row or vertical alignment/spacing if flex-direction is column)

For instance, if flex-direction is row (default):

`flex-start;` Align children *horizontally* left

`flex-end;` Align children *horizontally* right

`center;` Align children *horizontally* centered *(amaze!)*

`space-between;` Distribute children *horizontally* evenly across entire width

`space-around;` Distribute children *horizontally* evenly across entire width (but with space on the edges

## 2. `align-items:` along *secondary* axis

(set vertical alignment if flex-direction is row or horizontal alignment if flex-direction is column)

For instance, if flex-direction is row (default):

`flex-start;` Align children *vertically* top

`flex-end;` Align children *vertically* bottom

`center;` Align children *vertically* centered *(amaze!)*

`baseline;` Aligned children *vertically* so their baselines align *(doesn't really work)*

`stretch;` Force children to be height of container *(great for columns)*

## See it in action:

http://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/

## In my opinion:

These should have been named:

`flex-x:` alignment/spacing in primary axis

`flex-y:` alignment in secondary axis

But with HTML you can never have nice things.  Never.

Comment: The align-items property of flex-box aligns the items inside a flex container along the cross axis just like justify-content does along the main axis. (For the default flex-direction: row the cross axis corresponds to vertical and the main axis corresponds to horizontal. With flex-direction: column those two are interchanged respectively).

Comment: I think I mentioned this in the note at the top of my answer

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice.

Comment: why couldn't they just call it vertical and horizontal alignment haha

Comment: Unfortunately for simplification, the effect of `justify-content` and `align-items` changes depending on the `flex-direction`. E.g. if `flex-direction` is set to `column`, `justify-content` affects vertical alignment, and vice versa.

Comment: @ericso That is a copout, DanielKobe is correct: they could have easily named it flex-x, flex-y, or even flex-primary, flex-secondary in a way that indicates the axis can change.  The current names are ridiculous, inconsistent, and confusing to those learning.  They give no indication that they are related to eachother, or to flexbox.  Words like justify and align are already polluted by other css rules like vertical-align etc.  Words like content and items are mismatched.  I just cant even anymore.

Comment: @FEA5T not saying it's not a copout, just saying that it's possible that's the reasoning behind the avoidance of using flex-x, flex-y, etc. I mostly agree with the sentiment that it should be flex-x, flex-y.

Comment: This definition is incorrect. It isn't about horizontal and vertical. It's about main axis and cross axis. justify-content acts on the main axis and align-items acts on the cross axis. If the flex-direction is horizontal then this answer is correct. If the flex-direction is vertical then it isn't.

Comment: @pedr See my note up top?  This explanation makes a poor naming convention approachable, while making many notes of the primary and secondary axis you mentioned.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to give my own opionion... but..

Comment: Totally agreed on the naming suggestion, some parts of the html world are messy..., only makes the life for beginners miserable ....

Comment: Guys you can also use CSS property `place-items` as a shorthand for `justify-content` and `align-items`

Comment: @Acidic9 Place-items is short for justify-items not justify-content.  Justify-items is for css grid not flexbox.

Comment: Yep, the names could not have been worse. I'm a little ashamed to say that, but I have been using flexbox for years and did not know you can center along the secondary axis or that align-items is a flex property. I used to create wrapper elements with flex direction in the other axis to center vertically in a row. Luckily I have found this answer, better late than never. Thank you!

Comment: @Robot I think the terminology comes from typography. Justification is more about the space between elements whereas alignment describes the positioning to a line. This image was helpful in understanding: https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2018/07/shutterstock-align-typography-example-copy2.jpg