# Ionic 3 Grid on Larger device is not working as expected (Hope I did it wrongly)

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, flexbox, ionic3

I'm using `Ionic 3` `flexbox` grid system as shown below.This is a `Modal` `controller.

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row class="header">
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row padding class="details">
      <ion-col>
        <form [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm" (submit)="goToNext()" novalidate>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
              <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Distributor ID" formControlName="distributorId"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <button ion-button block class="button-radius-25" type="submit"><span>Next <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon></span></button>
          <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label class="font-size-14" text-center>Not a member? Sign up now!</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </form>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
 .content {
        ion-grid {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .header {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .details {
            flex: 3;
        }
    }
```

**Mobile device - No issues**

[image]

But on the **desktop**, it shows as below.

[image]

Q: It seems very bad on a larger device.How can I keep the same kind of ratio (I mean small sizes on components for `Button` and `textbox`) and centered the content on the larger device too? Hope you'll give the suggestions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `col-sm-, col-md-`... to change item size in different screen size:

```
<ion-row padding class="details">
      <ion-col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12>
        <form [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm" (submit)="goToNext()" novalidate>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
              <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Distributor ID" formControlName="distributorId"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <button ion-button block class="button-radius-25" type="submit"><span>Next <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon></span></button>
          <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label class="font-size-14" text-center>Not a member? Sign up now!</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </form>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

and to center item:

```
.details{
   justify-content: center;
}
```

See more about [ionic grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/)

Comment: Oh..Wonderfull.It is working.Thanks.Yes, I'm reading the doc.Can you please explain the magic you did above?

Comment: No magic here. Ionic grid did all the job. I just add `col-lg-6` for `screen > 992px`, `col-md-6` for `screen > 768px` and `col-12` for all screen. `col-6` mean `width: 50%` and`col-12` mean `width: 100%`

Comment: I have a confusion here is hence having only one column in the row.I know row can have maximum 12 columns.But when we give it `col-lg-6` for one column what will happen on a larger device?What is the difference of `col-lg-12` and `col-lg-6` when we have only one column? How it behaves?

Comment: It is so hard to explain all in comment. Let take an example and you will understand. Just add `col-12 col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6` to one col and inspect it in desktop screen view. You will see the difference. It is just css. If you still have confusion, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I did that and now it seems fine.One question: When this fire   `col-12`? On which device size?

Comment: `col-12` for devices have `screen-widh  >= 0`. It means all devices. Context of `col- col-md col-lg`... is described very clearly in [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#default-breakpoints). Please take a look at it

Comment: Can you tell me why we cannot use `align-items-center` instead of `justify-content: center;`? What does `align-items-center` do? It is not clear for me when I went to the doc.

Comment: Oh. It is not related to ionic grid. It is [flexbox css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can see difference beetwen them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049262/difference-between-justify-content-vs-align-items)

Comment: Oh..Great.Thank you so much for all the support.Now I have huge knowledge about this awesome grid system :)

Comment: Glad to help :D.

Comment: Another question:You can see that this hack here `<ion-row class="header"></ion-row>`.I have used that to give a  distance from header to `textbox` using `flex`.can I do that without that ugly hack? I need to give it as responsive way.Not just by using `margin-top`.Any thoughts?

Comment: Depend of your html structure we will choose the way to add `margin-top`. But i think add an `ion-row` is not a good way. Please add a plunker contain your code.