# Flex items of same height

Tags: css, flexbox

Im having problem Flex items Im trying to create flex containers of same height but its not working, could someone now what would be the issue
I tried with flex:1, and other properties but it just wont work 
Here is my sample code:

[Sample Layout](https://jsfiddle.net/gdqs59oc/)

```css
.recent-wrapper.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px 50px 40px 50px;
}

.post-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #999;
}

article.popular_posts {
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 1%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid-date {
  background-color: rgb(237, 43, 71);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 48px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
}

.post-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-wrapper container">
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/f-16-min.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 07</span>
      <span class="month"> Oct</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> Ф-16 Блок 70/72 “ПОСЛЕДЊИ ФАЛКОН” </h2>
      <p>Захваљујући уговорима о куповини вишенаменског борбеног авиона Ф-16”Figthing Falcon”&nbsp; БЛОК 70/72&nbsp;који су са његовим призвођачем, америчком компанијом “Локид Мартин” потписали</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/naoruzanje/f-16-blok-70-72-poslednji-falkon/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/win-azur-featured.jpeg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 07</span>
      <span class="month"> Oct</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> СТИЖЕ АЖУРУРИРАЊЕ за “WINDOWS 10” </h2>
      <p>Добре вести! Највећа светска корпорација “IT” технологије “Мicrosoft” са седиште у граду Редмонд у америчкој савезној држави Вашингтон, најавла је</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/nauka/stize-azururiranje-za-windows-10/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/9_114950d1-min.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 30</span>
      <span class="month"> Sep</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> РУСКИ МОРСКИ ДУХ </h2>
      <p>Гоестратег први пут у рубрици “Војска и наоружање” посвећује пажњу једном систему морнарице. У питању је нова руска “невидљива и</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/naoruzanje/ruski-morski-duh/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `align-items: center;` from `div.recent-wrapper.container`

Comment: I added to example from the link to your question, because each question MUST include a [mcve] in the question body itself

Comment: @AlonEitanYou should also tidy the code when you do that.

Comment: @connexo I never notice the small `tidy` button there up until now, will do it in future :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36004926/3597276

Comment: thanx you Zohir , your solution works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `align-items:center` which tries to align your 3 `articles` center vertically. And because your elements are not equal in height ( `post-container` height differs) they are aligned vertically in the center of your container but they are not 'equalized' in height.

Remove `align-items:center` and you will be ok.

If you want to align horizontally use `justify-content:center`. Keep in mind that the direction ( row/column ) changes the XY axes. Read more here -> [align-items / justify-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049262/difference-between-justify-content-vs-align-items)

See result in snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdqs59oc/1/)

```css
.recent-wrapper.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*align-items: center; */
  padding: 50px 50px 40px 50px;
}

.post-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #999;
}

article.popular_posts {
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 1%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid-date {
  background-color: rgb(237, 43, 71);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 48px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
}

.post-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-wrapper container">
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/f-16-min.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 07</span>
      <span class="month"> Oct</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> Ф-16 Блок 70/72 “ПОСЛЕДЊИ ФАЛКОН” </h2>
      <p>Захваљујући уговорима о куповини вишенаменског борбеног авиона Ф-16”Figthing Falcon”&nbsp; БЛОК 70/72&nbsp;који су са његовим призвођачем, америчком компанијом “Локид Мартин” потписали</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/naoruzanje/f-16-blok-70-72-poslednji-falkon/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/win-azur-featured.jpeg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 07</span>
      <span class="month"> Oct</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> СТИЖЕ АЖУРУРИРАЊЕ за “WINDOWS 10” </h2>
      <p>Добре вести! Највећа светска корпорација “IT” технологије “Мicrosoft” са седиште у граду Редмонд у америчкој савезној држави Вашингтон, најавла је</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/nauka/stize-azururiranje-za-windows-10/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="popular_posts">
    <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('https://geostrateg.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/9_114950d1-min.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-date">
      <span class="day"> 30</span>
      <span class="month"> Sep</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
      <h2> РУСКИ МОРСКИ ДУХ </h2>
      <p>Гоестратег први пут у рубрици “Војска и наоружање” посвећује пажњу једном систему морнарице. У питању је нова руска “невидљива и</p>
      <div class="submit-btn">
        <a href="https://geostrateg.com/naoruzanje/ruski-morski-duh/" class="read-more">Сазнај Више</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: one more quick question, how could i put .submit-btn always at the end of my post-container, I just think with position relative but is there any way use flex ??