# align items to the right using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

how to align a flex item to the right?

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    text-align: right; //nothing happens
}

<div className="row">
    <div className="col">content</div>
</div>
```

the output of this is something like

```
| content                   |
```

and I´m looking for

```
|                   content |
```

Comment: justify-content: flex-end;

Comment: .`col{margin-left:auto;}` works too

Answer (score 1):

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

First, you need to specify the direction of items (flex-direction) as row (horizontally) or column (vertically).

Then, if direction is row, align items using **justify-content** property with **flex-end** value. This will align items from the right to left (from the end of row to the start) / (oX axis)

If direction is column, align items using **align-items** property which have almost same values as justify-content, but is configured for vertically align (oY axis)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049262/difference-between-justify-content-vs-align-items) can help.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Aligning items in `flex` needs to be handled using `justify-content` or `align-items`

You need to use `justify-content` in your code:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

When you use `display:flex` for an element it has a default `flex-direction` with value of `row`. it means your inner elements will be placed in a row. This direction(row) is your main direction. `justify-content` will specify the location of your items in their main direction.

The value of `justify-content` can be `flex-start`, `flex-end`, etc. You need to set it to `flex-end` which in your situation means right side.

I highly recommend you to read the below link for more information:

> justify-content: 
>   This defines the alignment along the main axis. It helps distribute extra free space leftover when either all the flex items on a line are inflexible, or are flexible but have reached their maximum size. It also exerts some control over the alignment of items when they overflow the line. [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.